# Field extension $K(α, β) : K$ degree and relation to subfields $K(\alpha):K$ and $K(\beta):K$

Tags: galois-theory

I am currently beginning my study of Galois theory and was thinking about the following theorem:

**Theorem.**
Let $N = K(\alpha)$ and $M = K(\beta)$ be two simple extensions of K, with finite
degrees $[K(\alpha):K]=a$ and $[K(\beta):K]=b$ respectively.
Let $c = [K(α, β) : K]$.
Then $\mathrm{lcm}(a,b)\leq c\leq ab$.

This can easily be proven with Tower Law and I have no problem with that.

.

I have played around with extensions and how they fit the theorem, to see if I understand it. Examples I have come up with are:

$lcm(a,b)= c= ab$ is true whenever $a$,$b$ are coprime

$lcm(a,b)< c= ab$ is true for for extensions such as $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2,i)$ or $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2,\sqrt3)$

$lcm(a,b)= c<ab$ is true for $\alpha=\beta$, since $c=a=b = lcm(a,b) < ab$, or example $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3},\omega)=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3})$, where $\omega$ is a cube root of unity.

But I couldn't think of examples where both inequalities are strict:
$lcm(a,b)< c< ab$
Do such extensions exist? If so, can anyone give me examples, and what conditions have to be met for this to be the case?

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha) = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3},\sqrt{5},\sqrt{7})$, $\mathbb{Q}(\beta)=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3},\sqrt{5},\sqrt{7},\sqrt{11})$, $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha,\beta)=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3},\sqrt{5},\sqrt{7},\sqrt{11})$. Then $a=16$, $b=16$, $c=32$, so $\mathrm{lcm}(a,b)=16\lt 32\lt 128=ab$.

Comment: Note that you can say more than just $\mathrm{lcm}(a,b)\leq c\leq ab$. You know that $a$ and $b$ divide $c$, so you know that $\mathrm{lcm}(a,b)$ *divides* $c$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thanks for the example! I know that $a,b|c$ as part of the theorem's proof; I guess that is quite a bit more specific than a simple $\leq$.

Comment: It could have been smaller, but I was editing an idea in my head. Just take $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3},\sqrt{5})$. The compositum has order $8$, each extension has order $4$, and $4\lt 8\lt 16$.

Comment: Got it. Does this mean the strict inequality happens if each subfield shares a common generator (in your case, $\sqrt{3}$)? Or is that just a specific case?

Comment: By the way, the condition for $[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha,\beta):\mathbb{Q}]=[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha):\mathbb{Q}][\mathbb{Q}(\beta):\mathbb{Q}]$ is "linear disjointness". From Lang's *Algebra*: $K$ is said to be linearly disjoint from $L$ over $k$ if and only if every finite set of elements of $K$ that is linearly independent over $k$ is also linearly independent over $L$.

Comment: It's a specific case. Remember that finite extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$ are simple, and we actually have $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3}) = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})$. Generating sets don't have to have anything in common. But if $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)\cap\mathbb{Q}(\beta)\neq \mathbb{Q}$, then you cannot have the extension have degree $ab$.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Thanks so much for clearing this up for me!

Comment: Is $16 \times 16$ really 128? :-)